# Python - replace a part of a list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace

I have a string, for example :

```
s = '000025'
```

now I want to replace `s[:2]` with some string ('ss')

- I tried simple assignment ( `s[:2] = 'ss'` ) but it didn't work
- replace method didn't work either

`s.replace('00', 'ss', 1)` works but I'm looking for another solution

how can I do it ?

Comment: Strings are immutable objects, you cannot change them in-place.You can instead do `s = 'ss' + s[2:]`.

Comment: Strings in python are immutable - your best bet would be to make a new string with what you want in it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why aren't you using `s = ss + s[2:]`?